# ¿Como puedo instalar instalar Robo3t(Robomongo) en Debian Linux, especificamente el que ofrecen las Chromebooks?

Tags: linux, mongodb, shell, debian, terminal

tengo una Chromebook con Linux Instalado, he querido instalar Robo3t pero no he podido de ninguna manera...

He intentado:

- Extraer el tar.gz y en la carpeta de bin intente clicar en el archivo robo3t pero solo se descarga nuevamente el archivo
- Usar snapcraft en la terminal pero me aparece un error de incompatibilidad.

Gracias.

Comment: Hola, el sitio adecuado para tu pregunta podría ser [Software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) este está orientado hacia problemas ligados a la escritura de código. Difícilmente sea respondida a causa de las políticas del sitio.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo preguntare ahi!